# Updating input field by leaving

Tags: laravel, updates, laravel-livewire

Is it possible with Laravel livewire to change a field in the database when leaving the input field?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `wire:model.lazy` to achieve an action when leaving (loosing focus) on an input field.

```
<div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" wire:model.lazy="billingRate">
</div>

class Rate extends Component
{
     public $billingRate;


    public function updatedBillingRate(){

       dd($this->billingRate);     // don't forget to use $this to access class property

        // persist to database here
    }
}
```

In the above example, whenever billingRate value changes, it will trigger the `updatedBillingRate()` method.

Please checkout a similar thred on laracast here (https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/livewire/livewire-how-to-action-the-value-of-an-input-without-a-button)

Comment: You can also do the same thing using updated hook. public function updated($name,$value).

Comment: The actual syntax for lazy loading is wire:model.lazy instead of wire:model:lazy

Answer (score 0):

In my own perspective, you can implement JavaScript event listener when leaving the input field, an ajax request will fire-up to update the database.